# Stop node drop event with primeng p-tree component

Tags: angular, tree, primeng

I am using primeng p-tree component and i would like to forbid some node type to be drop inside another node type.

for exemple i have node with type folder and another node with type file and i only want that node of type file move inside a node of type folder. I want to forbid moving folder node inside another folder node.  (and other rules

```
<p-tree [value]="filesTree7" draggableNodes="true" droppableNodes="true" dragdropScope="files" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedFile2" [contextMenu]="cm" (contextmenu)="onContextMenu($event)"
          (onNodeDrop)="onNodeDrop($event)"></p-tree>
```

I tried to stop propagation of the drop like this :

```
onNodeDrop(event) {
    console.log("onNodeDrop");
    event.originalEvent.stopPropagation();
    event.originalEvent.preventDefault();
    return;
}
```

but it is not working.

when i have a look to primeng code here : [primeng tree component code source](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/tree/tree.ts) it seems that **onNodeDrop** event is emit too late.

Do you have any ideas how i can implement what i need ?

Comment: wrong tagging... read the description of them all and correct the tags

Comment: I have corrected one thanks

Comment: I'm facing the same problem now. Did you solve this?

Comment: unfortunately I could not do what I wanted with the primeng component. So I looked for another component with more options on the tree and I found dragula https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula Hope its help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until [this](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/3544) is implemented, the workaround could be to override the `allowDrop` [method](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/8c17830d7e6510cd460b0655388a3caee24eb0b6/src/app/components/tree/tree.ts#L699) of the `Tree` component and write your own implementation of the drop logic.
However you may (actually you should) want to use the drop logic covered in the original method and just add your bit.

Now `prototyping` might look like this:

- In the component where you have used `pTree`, get the `Tree` via `ViewChild`

  ```
  @ViewChild(Tree) tree: Tree;
  ```
- And then in the `constructor`, or `ngOnInit` or whatever suites your case, `prototype` the `allowDrop`

  ```
  Tree.prototype.allowDrop = (dragNode: any, dropNode: any, dragNodeScope: any): boolean => {
    return this._overrideAllowDrop(dragNode, dropNode, dragNodeScope)
  }
  ```

`_overrideAllowDrop` is used for brevity purpose. To cancel the drop just `return false`.

Moreover, you can utilize `dragDropService` of the tree instance to show error messages, in case drop failed.

For example:

```
this.tree.dragDropService.dragStop$.subscribe((data) => {
  if(this.failed){ // set failed to true in your custom drop logic
    alert('Error!')
  }
})
```

But this workaround has the disadvantage that the drop logic should be on the UI side and if your logic requires the backend interference, this workaround might not be of that much help.

Although the backend was involved in my case but the logic was simple so i moved it on the UI side and thus `prototyping` serves the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

If you want that a single node isn't droppable or draggable you must set params  draggable/droppable in array:

```
{
    "label": "Note e Commenti",
    "icon": "fa-file-word-o",
    "draggable":false,
    "droppable":false,
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": "Note e Commenti",
        "testo": "Note e Commenti",
        "idCategoria": 2,
        "idTipologia": 1
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This has some additional details that are important, especially the bind() function

```
    export class myClass implements AfterViewInit {
      @ViewChild('primeTree') primeTree: Tree;  // named in HTML
    
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        // get the original function AND bind it to the tree - important!
        const originalAllowDrop = this.primeTree.allowDrop.bind(this.primeTree);
        
        // replace the allowDrop function with this
        this.primeTree.allowDrop = (dragNode: TreeNode, dropNode: TreeNode, dragNodeScope: any): boolean => {
          // let the original function do the pre-check, and then check for special cases
          return originalAllowDrop(dragNode, dropNode, dragNodeScope) && this.allowDrop(dragNode, dropNode, dragNodeScope);
        }

  }

  private allowDrop(dragNode: TreeNode, dropNode: TreeNode, dragNodeScope: any): boolean {
    // your logic here
    if (imNotHappy) {
      return false
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```